# In Google Docs Always a blank line above & below where I insert a table?

Tags: css, google-docs

In Google Docs, when I insert a table in Header or in Footer, there seem to be always a blank line above & below the table. See the screenshot below.
How do I prevent that?

Header screenshot  :
[image]
Footer screenshot :[image]

Comment: Same question here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/always-a-blank-line-above-where-i-insert-a-table

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a web application, not a programming question. It could be asked on [webapps.se].

Answer (score 3):

It's by design, there's nothing you can do to completely remove the space.

You can reduce the font size of the space to make it smaller.